# What is the actual formula to find the vertices of an animation frame in using a BVH file?

Tags: unity, 3d, mathematics, javascript, algorithm

I've read [this tutorial](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/cs-838-1999/Jeff/BVH.html) and tried many formulas to build the skeleton. I am able to build it without the rotations, but those break everything. This, for example, is a simplified code for one of my attempts:

```
/* Pseudocode using overloaded operators for illustration purposes */
var build_skeleton = function(motion,frame_number){
    positions = [];
    deg_to_rad = Math.PI/180;

    (function travel_tree(node,old_pos){
        pos = [node.offsetX, node.offsetY, node.offsetZ];

        frame = node.frames[frame_number];

        x_rotation = quat_from_axis_angle([1,0,0],frame[2] * deg_ro_rad);
        y_rotation = quat_from_axis_angle([0,1,0],frame[1] * deg_ro_rad);
        z_rotation = quat_from_axis_angle([0,0,1],frame[0] * deg_ro_rad);
        rotation = x_rotation * y_rotation * z_rotation;

        pos = old_pos + apply_quaternion(rotation, pos);

        positions.push(pos);

        node.children.map(function(a){ return travel_tree(a,pos); })
    })(motion.root,[0,0,0]);

    return positions;
};
```

I've tried many variations of this, switching axes, signals etc. Nothing seems to work. So what is the formula to find the positions of the vertexes of an animation on the BVH format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that tutorial actually contains all you need. It mentions that the order of rotations is Z, then X, then Y.
I don't know Unity's quaternions, but you are either doing Z then Y then X, or the reverse.

Try swapping x_rotation and y_rotation when you calculate your final rotation.

Comment: I have tried, it does not work. I have actually made a function to test every possible permutation of every possible param and signal and watched it for a few minutes. In the end, I managed to solve my issue by redoing everything using matrices instead of quaternions - and even this only worked because I followed detail by detail the bvh report (not this tutorial). I'll post the code if someone requests it. Thanks.